# Expanding out multiplied terms

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

Is there any command in *Mathematica* to expand terms like $x^2\, y^3$ to $x\,x\,y\,y\,y$?

I tried `PowerExpansion`, but it works for expressions like $(x\,y)^2$ which gives $x^2\,y^2$.

Comment: You could write a routine yourself using `Row[]` and `ConstantArray[]`…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a task for [`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html)/[`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) and `HoldForm`:

```
powerProductForm[expr_] :=
 With[{expanded = Inactivate[
      expr /. Power[u_, n_Integer?Positive] :>
        Inactive[Times] @@ ConstantArray[u, n],
      Times
      ] /.
     prod : Inactive[Times][__] :> Flatten[prod]},
  Activate@HoldForm[expanded]];
```

Then

```
In[2]:= powerProductForm[x^2*y^3 + x*y^2 + 2*z^3*w^4]
Out[2]= x y y + x x y y y + 2 w w w w z z z
```

Comment: I'd use `Defer[]` instead of `HoldForm[]` myself...

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get your output. It gives `Activate[Inactivate` blah blah blah!!

Comment: @MEDVIS What version of Mathematica are you using? `Inactivate` was introduced in 10.0.

Comment: @Pillsy So that's the reason... I'm using version 9. I'll try it with another computer

Answer (score 8):

J. M. beat me to it with the comment, but here's some example code:

```
f=(x^2 y^3);

Row@
  Flatten@
    (ConstantArray @@@
      Cases[#, Power[b_, e_] :> {b, e}] &@
    f)
```

You should think about whether you need the expansion purely for display purposes though, or whether you need to do any further manipulation. `xxyyy` in the above example is something complete different to Mathematica than `x^2 y^3`.

Comment: In a similar vein: `With[{prod = Join @@ (x^2 y^3 /. {Times -> List, Power -> ConstantArray})}, Defer[prod] /. List -> Times]`.

Comment: I actually prefer you solution because you can plug it right back in and recover the original form.

Comment: "you can plug it right back in and recover the original form." - that was the intention, yes. :)

Comment: I guessed so, I just wanted to make it more explicit ;)

Answer (score 5):

If this is for display purposes you could use `Format`:

```
Format[fmt[{x_, n_}], TraditionalForm] := Row@Table[x, {n}]
fmt[{x_, 0}] := 1
fun[poly_, {var__}] := With[{cr = CoefficientRules[poly, {var}]},
  Times @@ MapThread[fmt[{#2, #1}] &, {#, {var}}] & /@ 
     cr[[All, 1]].cr[[All, 2]] // TraditionalForm
  ]
```

For example:

```
fun[3 x^2 z^6 + x^2 y^3 + z^5 x y^4 + 4 x y z, {x, y, z}]
```

yields:

[image]