# Write x^3 as x*x*x

Tags: expression-manipulation

I use mathematica compute functions I need for some external coding. However I can't use terms like `x^2+y^3` since my programming language needs this term written as `x*x+y*y*y`. I would love to copy and paste the results from mathematica so how do I convert these terms?

Comment: Something like `StringReplace["x^2+y^3", a : LetterCharacter ~~ "^" ~~ n : DigitCharacter :> StringRiffle[ConstantArray[a, FromDigits[n]], "*"]]`?

Comment: Kinda works but kinda not since mathematica dont uses ^ to write a power.

Comment: You can first use `ToString@InputForm[expr]` to get a string with powers written in `^` notation

Comment: Or you can look at this previous post: [Post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98381/expanding-out-multiplied-terms)

Comment: Didnt find that one - thanks @PinoSavana

Comment: I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433817/exporting-expressions-to-c-part-1-wolfram-mathematica) ten years ago (!!!) about tweaking the output of "CForm" (to change Power to repeated multiplication); Leonid Schifrin wrote a great reply that solved my problem.  So it is really quite interesting to me to see the approaches mentioned to this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want it in string form you can do it like this

```
x^3 /. Power -> (StringRiffle[#, "*"] &@ConstantArray[#1, #2] &)
```

> "x * x * x"

This makes use of the fact that x^3 is internally written as `Power[x,3]`.

Comment: Works. Thank you!

Comment: `x^3 /. Power[a_, n_] :> Inactive[Times] @@ ConstantArray[a, n]` is another way to do it. This makes it easy to convert back as well with `Activate`.

Comment: also `x^2 + y^3 /.  Power -> Apply[Inactive @ Times] @* ConstantArray`

Answer (score 7):

Since you mention another language, here's a method using [`CForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CForm):

```
Unprotect[Power];

Power /: Format[x_Symbol^n_Integer?Positive, CForm] := SequenceForm @@ Riffle[
    ConstantArray[x, n],
    Format["*", OutputForm]
]

Protect[Power];
```

Example:

```
x^2+y^3 //CForm

x*x + y*y*y
```