# Replace repeated items differently

Tags: replacement, symbols, rule

So I have a simple replacement rule of the following form:

`expr/.f[a_,b_]:> g[a,#]g[b,#]&@func[]`

i.e. I want to replace each function f[a,b] with two factorised functions g[a,#]g[b,#]. However, if f is repeated in expr, I would like it to run func[] again to refresh the values of #. A simple example is

```
list = {a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8};
$dummy = 1; (* Global variable *)
func[] := Module[{out},
  out = list[[1 + $dummy]];
  $dummy = $dummy + f;
  out[[1]]
  ] (* Spits out a new item from the list each time it's called, e.g. *)

func[]
func[]

(* Output *)
a1
a2

(* Testing gives *)
expr = f[1,2];
expr/.f[a_,b_]:> g[a,#]g[b,#]&@func[]
(* Output *)
g[1,a1]g[2,a1]
```

Now this works fine, but the problem is when I want to evaluate products, powers etc and assign different outputs of func[] for each f[a,b]. For example for `expr = f[1,2]f[3,4]` I get

```
(* Output *)
g[1,a1]g[2,a1]g[3,a1]g[4,a1]
```

whereas what I want is

```
(* Output *)
g[1,a1]g[2,a1]g[3,a2]g[4,a2]
```

I figured I might want to use ReplacePart[] or something, but maybe there is a slicker way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I think you just need parentheses around the right side of the rule, i.e. `f[a_,b_]:>(g[a,#]g[b,#]&@func[])`

Comment: It is difficult to understand what the title is about. As this question could be useful to other members, perhaps the title could be more explicit if it was changed to something like " Replacement rule that changes/updates after each replacement" or "Naming each occurrence of a pattern differently".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Symbol`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Symbol.html) and
[`RuleDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) with a [`CompoundExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html) utilising [`Increment`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Increment.html) on your global variable.

With

```
$i = 0;
rule = f[a_, b_] :> ($i++; 
    g[a, #] g[b, #] &@Symbol["a" <> ToString@$i]);
```

Then

```
$i = 0;
f[1, 2] /. rule
```

> ```
> g[1, a1] g[2, a1]
> ```

and

```
$i = 0;
f[1, 2] f[3, 4] /. rule
```

> ```
> g[1, a1] g[2, a1] g[3, a2] g[4, a2]
> ```

and

```
$i = 0;
(f[1, 2]/f[3, 4]) f[5, 6] /. rule
```

> ```
> (g[1, a1] g[2, a1] g[5, a3] g[6, a3])/(g[3, a2] g[4, a2])
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, thanks!

Comment: one issue is that it doesn't work for f[a,b]^n... Is there a slick workaround I can use for this? Edit: I added a workaround... But perhaps there is a slicker way :)

Comment: @Akoben it works fine for `f[a,b]^n` in Mma 13.1 on Win 10 Pro.  Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Akoben's answer, the automatic gathering of products into `Power` can be a nuisance when making programs that use symbolic operations/rules that involve `Times`.
One option is to use `Inactive[Times]` to split the power into products. Most of the function below can be found for example in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98391/86543) (the function stoppower below also replaces Times by Inactive[Times] everywhere in the expression to have a more homogeneous expression):

---

**EDIT** I noticed a maybe undesirable effect when using the code below.

```
s*r*r^2*xr // stoppower // InputForm
```

`Inactive[Times][ Inactive[Times][r, r, r], s,  xr]`

that is, stoppower transforms `s*r*r^2*xr` to `(r*r*r)*xr*s` where `(r*r*r)` is `Inactive[Times][r, r, r]` above. This is because `Inactive[Times]` does not not seem to inherit the [`Flat`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat.html) attribute from `Times`. One may instead define a custom times:

```
ClearAll[times];
times = Diamond;
SetAttributes[Diamond, DeleteCases[Attributes[Times], Protected]];
```

and then use stoppower2 instead of stoppower:

```
stoppower2[x_] := 
 x /. Times -> times /. a_^b_ :> times @@ ConstantArray[a, b]
```

With the example below:

```
$i = 0;

rule = f[a_, b_] :> ($i++;
    g[a, #]*g[b, #] &@Symbol["a" <> ToString@$i]);

f[1, 2]^2*f[3, 4] + 5*h[ba, bb] // stoppower2 // ReplaceAll[rule] // 
 ReplaceAll[times -> Times]
```

The code for `expand` below also worked using stoppower2 instead of stoppower in the example provided for `expand` below.

**End of edit**

---

**Previous version**

```
stoppower[x_] := x /. Times -> Inactive@Times /. a_^b_ :> 
Inactive[Times] @@ ConstantArray[a, b]
```

Now there is no need to use a second rule, no need to use `Product` and no need to use `Optional` with f[a_, b_]^n_. (notice the . at the end of _ see comment by Lukas Lang below @Akoben's answer for further details on this pattern).

Example (using @Edmund 's answer):

```
$i = 0;

rule = f[a_, b_] :> ($i++;
   g[a, #] g[b, #] &@Symbol["a" <> ToString@$i]);

f[1, 2]^2 f[3, 4] + 5*h[ba, bb] // stoppower // ReplaceAll[rule] // Activate
```

Output: `(* g[1, a1] g[1, a2] g[2, a1] g[2, a2] g[3, a3] g[4, a3] + 5 h[ba, bb] *)`

---

In the light of the above example one might want to swap Times for Inactive[Times] and use Activate only when needed. One issue might be that Expand does not distribute Inactive[Times]. A possible solution might be to define a custom expand function using:

```
expand = Map[Distribute, #, Infinity] &
```

Example:

```
a^3*(g + u) + g*n*4*(j + bb*s) // stoppower // expand
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @Edmunds fantastic answer, as a quick workaround to operate on powers

```
$i = 0;
rule = {f[a_, b_]^n_ :> Product[($i++;
      g[a, #] g[b, #] &@Symbol["a" <> ToString@$i]), {i, n}], 
   f[a_, b_] :> ($i++;
     g[a, #] g[b, #] &@Symbol["a" <> ToString@$i])};

f[1, 2]^2 f[3, 4] /. rule
g[1, a1] g[1, a2] g[2, a1] g[2, a2] g[3, a3] g[4, a3]
```

Comment: You should be able to use `f[a_,b_]^n_. :> …` (notice the dot in `_.`) to match both cases with and without exponent.

Comment: Ahh thanks @LukasLang - what does this dot operator do? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: `n_.` is the short form for `Optional[n_]`, see the documentation for [`Optional`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html) and [`Default`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html). Effectively, it's telling Mathematica that the `n` doesn't need to be there, and if it is not, `n` should be assumed to take it's default value (which is `1` for `Power`/`^`). It's usually very tricky to get right, but for simple cases like this where you just want to allow expressions with and without exponents, it's quite straightforward once you know it exists.